# Get the name of the people who like a page on Facebook

Tags: java, facebook

I need your help please.

I'm developing a java application using restfb library, in which i want to get all the facebook users who liked my fan page on fb. I worked for many days to do that but i didn't find a solution.

I wrote this code but it return the number of likers only:

```
FacebookClient fb= new DefaultFacebookClient("ACCESS_TOKEN");
        Page page = fb.fetchObject("PAGE_ID", Page.class);
        System.out.println("My pages likes: " + page.getLikes());
```

Note that i'm getting the ACCESS_TOKEN from the Graph API Explorer when i'm logged in on the fb page, because i didn't find a way to get the token from java code. So when i logout i sea this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out.
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient$DefaultGraphFacebookExceptionMapper.exceptionForTypeAndMessage(DefaultFacebookClient.java:766)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.throwFacebookResponseStatusExceptionIfNecessary(DefaultFacebookClient.java:688)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequestAndProcessResponse(DefaultFacebookClient.java:630)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:592)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.makeRequest(DefaultFacebookClient.java:556)
    at com.restfb.DefaultFacebookClient.fetchObject(DefaultFacebookClient.java:244)
    at testrestfb.testfb.main(testfb.java:95)
```

Please help me to solve this problem..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could u better format our code with clarity and since ques is also related to facebook better would be add that tag as well

Comment: I think its not duplicate as user asked about restfb which is in java and above question is in PHP, so solving problem is different for new users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the information about such thing using fql query.

Please see below of Making a More Complex Call

Here we make the API call fql.query to execute a custom query.

```
// FQL query which asks Facebook for your friends' names,
// profile picture URLs, and network affiliations

String query =
  "SELECT name, pic_big, affiliations FROM user " +
  "WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=12345)";

// Executes an API call with result mapped to a list of classes we've defined.
// Note that you can pass in an arbitrary number of Parameters - here we
// send along the query as well as the "give me HTTPS URLs" flag

List<User> users =
  facebookClient.executeForList("fql.query", sessionKey, User.class,
    Parameter.with("query", query), Parameter.with("return_ssl_resources", "true"));
```

Details are [here](http://restfb.googlecode.com/svn-history/r37/trunk/RestFB/website/index.html)

Comment: thanks Imran for your reply, i tried your solution but it still require a valid access token when creating an instance of FacebookClient. So when i'm logged out from the fb page i receive the same error. Are there any method to generate valid access token in java?

Comment: This will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671694/restfb-using-a-facebook-app-to-get-the-users-access-token

Comment: You can mark it as correct answer, to help others.. :)

Comment: @Imran it shows error for session key....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187977/error-when-using-fql-query..